# cx_freeze No module named os

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I wanna freeze my python scripts into .exe files. I used to use pyinstaller but now the antivirus says it's a virus (so please don't tell me to use pyinstaller - unless you know how to fix the antivirus problem). I'm trying to use cx_freeze. I had problems with modules that didn't work so I entered them in the setup.py file. So here is my setup.py code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["matplotlib", "os", "pandas", "math", "sklearn","yellowbrick", "PySimpleGUI"]}

setup(name="Clustering Tool",
      version="1.5",
      description="",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options}, 
      executables = [Executable("clustering_tool_1.5.py")])
```

problem when the exe is created it launches and the console blinks and dies. I run the script through command prompt and it says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'os'
```

but I entered the os module with my packages. Am I missing something here? How can I include the os module in here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess single file build is unsupported one please check FAQ of `cx-freeze` [here](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables)
and more over `os` is built-in you dont have to explicitly install.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not trying to make a single file necessarily. Also, I know that I normally don't need to explicitly install os but I had the same error message so I tried to be explicit. In both cases I have this issue.